# UITabBar ios7 blur wont work on iPad 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios-simulator

I'm trying to use the blur effect on my ios 7 apps. I use the `UITabBar` blur trick, and it works well only on the emulator, but not on a real ios7 device. I am using an iPad 3 that's already using ios 7.

Did I forgot something ? I need it to work on an ios 7 device.

[image]

In build settings, my configuration

- **Base SDK** : iOS 7.0
- **Deployment Target** : iOS 6.0

Here is the source :

```
if (![catlistView viewWithTag:23] && [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.) {
    categoryListBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIToolbar* bgToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:categoryListBackground.frame];
    bgToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    bgToolbar.tag = 23;
    bgToolbar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:240./255. green:243./255. blue:243./255. alpha:0.9];
    [catlistView insertSubview:bgToolbar atIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `[bgToolbar setTranslucent:YES];`?

Comment: @zbMax it doesn't work

Comment: That's weird cause guidlines say : `In iOS 7, a translucent element blurs only the content directly behind it`...

Comment: yeah, this trick always work, I use it in my other apps. This is the first time I meet something like this.

Comment: What about setting barstyle to `UIBarStyleBlack` or `UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent` and then change the bar tint color?

Comment: Try setting the Deployment Target to iOS 7.0.

Comment: BTW - It's a simulator, not an emulator. Important difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blur is not enabled on iPad3 devices. (look at Control Center, Siri, Notification Center and you will notice there is no blur). 
If you like to add Blur effects to an iPad3 you have to blur the view yourself.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just try it create new project and run it on same device (ipad3) with same ios version (ios7) and it work well. you can look at screenshot here http://oi40.tinypic.com/2ez093a.jpg

Comment: @NovalAgungPrayogo that doesn't look blured at all, it only transparent like the screenshot you posted with your question..

Comment: @NovalAgungPrayogo yes it is transparent but not blured, like the Control Center for example is transparent on iPad3 but not blured. just compare the screenshot to a simulator run...

Comment: no, didn't you read my reply to zbMax ? I use it on my other apps and it work well. and you can find any other worked example on other thread at stackoverlow.

Comment: dude i have tested it with an iPad mini, an iPad2, iPad3 and iPad4 and UITabbar blur only works on iPad mini, iPad2 and iPad4 not iPad3

Comment: ok ok, thanks for your answer. so, there is no other solutions other than blurring myself ?

Comment: no sadly there is really no other solution then blurring it your self

Answer (score 1):

As said iPad3 and some other old devices (as iPhone 4) do not support blurred views, but try [FXBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView) it may serve your purpose.